# How to do something with react that if the url is equal to a certain string, something will be done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
    useEffect(()=>{
      const aLink = ul.current.querySelectorAll('li a')
      console.log('/'+window.location.href.split('/')[3]);
      aLink.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click' , (e)=>{
          console.log(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
          setActive(!active)
        })
        if(element.getAttribute('href') == '/'+ window.location.href.split('/')[3]) {
          element.classList.add('NavBar_active__Cvluy')
        }else{
          element.classList.remove('NavBar_active__Cvluy')
        }
      });
    } , [active])
```

Here is my code but it needs to be double clicked to recognize the current url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

I suggest not using an effect for what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you want to control an `active` state, but it is not clear what it does.

A better solution is (if you use react-router) to use a NavLink component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const linkClassName = ({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'NavBar_active__Cvluy' : '';

  return (
    <ul>
      <li><NavLink to="/home" className={linkClassName}>Home</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/about" className={linkClassName}>About</NavLink></li>
      <li><NavLink to="/contact" className={linkClassName}>Contact</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useLocation()` hook from react router dom.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
const location = useLocation();
if(location.pathname === '/url') {
   //do something what you want.
}
```